# Oracle Apex Get Set Variable from datepicker

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Oracle Apex 4.2
Oracle 11g

Below is some SQL that generates an interactive report.
I have 2 pages items both are date pickers named :P55_STARTD and P55_ENDD.

I've also have a button to fire a refresh on all the report region. But still get nothing. I thing this is some type of session issue. Any ideas guys.

```
Select * from 
(SELECT REPORT_MISSED_ORDERS_ALL.CUSTOMER_REF,
 REPORT_MISSED_ORDERS_ALL.LINE_NO,
 REPORT_MISSED_ORDERS_ALL.SKU,
 REPORT_MISSED_ORDERS_ALL.PICK_FROM,
 REPORT_MISSED_ORDERS_ALL.ORDERED_BY,
 REPORT_MISSED_ORDERS_ALL.HR,
 REPORT_MISSED_ORDERS_ALL.ORDER_PLACED_DATE,
 TO_CHAR(REPORT_MISSED_ORDERS_ALL.ORDER_PLACED_DATE, 'MONTH') AS months,
 LOGI_ORDERS.AUTH_TYPE_ID
   FROM REPORT_MISSED_ORDERS_ALL
      LEFT JOIN LOGI_ORDERS
      ON REPORT_MISSED_ORDERS_ALL.CUSTOMER_REF = LOGI_ORDERS.CALLNUMBER
      AND REPORT_MISSED_ORDERS_ALL.LINE_NO     = LOGI_ORDERS.LINE_NUMBER)t1
  where T1.AUTH_TYPE_ID is null 
  and trunc(t1.ORDER_PLACED_DATE) between :P55_STARTD and :P55_ENDD ;
```

Comment: Are you posting the item values?  They need to be in session state for the report SQL to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you put date items in "Page items to submit" field?
[image: IR apex submit items]